# C# SQL Server data storage

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing an application in c# that uses SQL Server database for storage propose.

My question might be a bit silly, but yet I don't understand something..

I use a lot of application that use SQL Server for storage, but it looks like the DB is inside the application and installed in the installation process.

Does every time I use my SQL Server db in my application I need to install a SQL Server in my client's computer ?

Or can I somehow wrap my database in the installation ?

It looks a bit weird to me that a SQL Server must be installed in every computer I want to install the application on - although it uses a very simple database.

Maybe the solution is to use some other storage option ?

Comment: You're looking for SQL CE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a database like SQL Server CE or SQLite which doesn't require installing a server.  It is just a single database file that is included with your program.

Comment: A single database file **plus** a few DLL's in the `bin` folder, to be precise...

Answer (score 0):

In teory you have to install only the client, but it is already installed in every Windows... You have just to config it. Run cliconfg on the command line. On 64 bit you have to choose which version (32 or 64 bit) to run

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice for this kind of scenario is to provide user interface that would allow the client to enter server name and credentials with enough privileges.

I wouldn’t create an application that would automatically install SQL Server on client’s computer because that’s too intrusive.

Just provide a nice and clean user interface in the installation process and your clients will be able to do the rest.

Yes, there are options for SQL Server Compact Edition and other similar stuff but you’ll also have a ton of restrictions with these versions.